# How to use syntax highlighting in next js?

Tags: next.js

I am able to parse the markdwon with the help of `remark` and `remark-html`. How can I add syntax highlighting features for the `code` element?

Answer (score 1):

I've been searched for ***TWO whole days*** trying to use remark/rehype ecosystem on syntax highlighting which is way more complex to use. I'm still working on searching, it's better to avoid remark/rehype ecosystem and try another method.

Here I share list of my search, just give you some subjective perspective so that you won't waste you too much time on things that not working. None of them will work as you expected, and their sample code are obscure or just broken codes.

1. https://github.com/remarkjs/remark-highlight.js

   - They move to support rehype. Are you a big fan of them wanna move as well?
2. https://github.com/sergioramos/remark-prism

   - You will get this error: `Module parse failed: Unexpected character '�'`
3. https://github.com/torchlight-api/remark-torchlight

   - They states on their website:  This client is still very much a work in progress. Please open issues! View it on github at *github.com/torchlight-api/remark* and this link is invalid.
4. https://github.com/rehypejs/rehype-highlight

   - It force you to use rehpye althought you can you remark-rehype for you to transfer easily. However, debug your code once you encounter some error will be helpless.
   - sample code use third-pary `v-file` to read file showing their code is working but not. and it reads html file not markdown file.
   - It's hard for you to grasp their concept to use their plugins to easily. It waste most of you valuable time to think what they think.

**I give up remark/rehype ecosystem and stay away from them. Good luck! :)**

Comment: Where did you see that message for [remark-torchlight](https://github.com/torchlight-api/remark-torchlight)? I don't see that message or any broken link. I just see the following which works fine: "See https://torchlight.dev/docs/clients/remark for full docs."